# For SEO, include JS files at start or end of HTML

Tags: javascript, html, seo, meta-tags

For SEO, I was confused by reading many blogs about whether to include my JS and CSS files at the starting or the ending of the page?
Also, where to include the META tags?
Which is the best way?
Currently, I code something like this:

```
<html>
///meta tags
//include CSS files
<head>
.....
</head>
<body>
....
....
....
//include JS files
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

For the page to render properly, I think those files should always be declared before the body tag so everything loads and gets cached before the actual page loads.

As for its effects on SEO, I think the only thing that would effect would be page load speed (assuming the files you are calling do not return a 404 error). CSS files get cached so they only really need to load once but not sure if JS files do or not...

As for you second question, I'm pretty sure which ever way helps the page load faster would be your best bet, run some tests!

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it best way because .Why?let me tell you

---

**CSS file:** These should be loaded before body because not styled body-content should never be presented to the user

---

**JS file:** these should be put at end because every user do manipulation on page after the page loads and it makes the page visible to user faster.

---

**Meta tags**:They are perfectly suitable for head tags.But personally i don't use them.

Comment: Okay. One thing more; include php inside is a better option or vice versa?
I mean 
`<?php echo "Dear ".$currentuser." please input the type of job for a potential candidate"; ?>'
**OR** 
`<html>Dear <?php echo $currentuser ?> please input the type of job for a potential candidate</html>`

Comment: php injection in html is always a "tradeoff between crap and shit". So it doesn't matter.

Comment: I agree with your answer, but what does any of it have to do with SEO?